# How to iterate character in csv reader python

Tags: python, loops, csv, character

I have a number of text files (.txt), the first one is named 1_1_A_A and the last one is named 10_10_B_C. The first element in the names goes from 1 to 10, the second also goes from 1 to 10, the third can be A or B and the fourth can be A, B or C. It makes a total of 600 instances. I want python to read them with CSV reader. For the first two elements, I use `%s` in two loops and it works properly. But what should I do to iterate the characters in third and fourth place?

The code is something like this, iterating the firs two elements:

```
for i in range (len(JobSize)):
    for j in range(len(Iteration)):
        with open('%s_%s_A_A.txt' % (JobSize[i], Iteration[j]), 'rt') as Data:
            reader = csv.reader(Data, delimiter='\t')
```

Comment: `for k in['A', 'B', ...]:`

Comment: But what is the problem of using the same thing "adding another two loops for the chars" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over any iterable the same way. It doesn't have to be a `range`; `for i in range(3):` does the same thing as `for i in [1, 2, 3]:`. And the values don't have to be ints—you can do `for i in ['A', 'B', 'C']`. Or, even more simply, a string is itself an iterable of characters, so `for i in 'ABC':`.

And, while we're at it, this means you can iterate over the lists `JobSize` and `Iteration` directly. Instead of using `for i in range(len(JobSize)):` and then `JobSize[i]`, just do `for i in JobSize:` and use `i` directly.

So:

```
for i in JobSize:
    for j in Iteration:
        for k in 'AB':
            for l in 'ABC':
                with open('%s_%s_%s_%s.txt' % (i, j, k, l), 'rt') as Data:
```

---

However, four levels of nesting is pretty ugly, and pushes your code off the right edge of the screen. You'll probably find this nicer with [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

> Roughly equivalent to nested for-loops… The nested loops cycle like an odometer with the rightmost element advancing on every iteration.

In other words, this does exactly the same thing as the above:

```
import itertools
for i, j, k, l in itertools.product(JobSize, Iteration, 'AB', 'ABC'):
    with open('%s_%s_%s_%s.txt' % (i, j, k, l), 'rt') as Data:
```

---

Or, even more simply: instead of using tuple unpacking to get separate `i, j, k, l` variables, just keep it as a single `ijkl` and pass it to [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
for ijkl in itertools.product(JobSize, Iteration, 'AB', 'ABC'):
    with open('_'.join(ijkl), 'rt') as Data:
```

---

If the elements of `JobSize` and `Iteration` aren't strings, that last version won't work—but if you [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) them all to strings, it works just as well as `%s`:

```
for ijkl in itertools.product(JobSize, Iteration, 'AB', 'ABC'):
    with open('_'.join(map(str, ijkl)), 'rt') as Data:
```

---

Of course you probably want to come up with a better name than `ijkl`. Maybe `name_components`?

Comment: Great. Iteration is simply 1 to 10, that I can use it directly. JobSize is a list of 10 different numbers ranging from 5 to 500. Thanks dude.

Comment: @user1594832 That's fine. If JobSize is `[5, 100, 20, 15, 50, 500, 12, 12, 99, 100]`, then `for i in JobSize:` will give you 5, then 100, then 20, etc. Try it out in the interactive interpreter: `for i in JobSize: print(i)`.

Comment: Yes, it works. Much better than writing in len(JobSize) and then referencing it as Jobsize[i]. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over any iterable, including strings like:

#### Code:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    for j in 'abc':
        print('{}_{}'.format(i, j))
```

#### Results:

```
1_a
1_b
1_c
2_a
2_b
2_c
3_a
3_b
3_c
```